# Magento add ordered item name and sku in same grid column

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add items details in to the order grid. These details (item name and sku) should display in one column. I added the below code in to the collection:

```
->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
    'products',
    '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name, \' \', x.sku)
                        FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                        WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                            AND x.product_type != \'configurable\') SEPARATOR ""',
    array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
)
```

That is working fine. But if there are more than one item in an order, I need to display them with a `<br />` (in a new line, but same column). Also should add a separator (`-`) in between sku and name.

Example:
in column one order item details should display as below:

```
Product 1 - sku 1
product 2 - sku 2
product 3 - sku 3
```

Can anyone please help me how to do that task. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use your own render for the column.

You should set the additional value where you're adding it:

```
$block->addColumn('product_names', array(
    'renderer' => 'mageworx_ordersgrid/adminhtml_sales_order_grid_renderer_products', 
    //...
```

Then, in the render you can transform received information from the column whatever you want using this method:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
```

You can use this example:

```
$html = '';
$products = explode('^', $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex())); // change ^ to your delimiter
foreach ($products as $key => $product) { 
    //... generate your html here
    $html .= $product . ' - ';
    //....
}

return $html;
```

Data in the column will stay untouched, but it will be displayed in the proper way.

Additionally, you can separate the columns `sku` and `product_name` to ease your work:

```
'product_names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`name` SEPARATOR \'\n\')'),
'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sku` SEPARATOR \'\n\')'),
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for the quick reply. This works. But after that i am facing another issue. I added a <br /> tag to beak the line in grid. But when I check the CSV <br /> tag has printing there instead of the line break. Can you please help for that too...

Comment: Try to use \n instead of <br/>.
[Generating CSV file for Excel, how to have a newline inside a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value)

Comment: Already tried that. Did not work :(

Comment: Share your CSV file, please.